# How to get a random character from a range in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unicode

Looking at Katakana characters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana#Unicode) how would I get a random character from a Unicode range?

I'm close with

```
String.fromCharCode(0x30A0 + Math.random() * 60);
```

The '60' is kind of a rough guess of the range. Is there a way to code in "U+30A0 ... U+30FF" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this :

```
String.fromCharCode(0x30A0 + Math.random() * (0x30FF-0x30A0+1));
```

Note that `0x30FF-0x30A0` is `95`, and if you want the last one you must add `1` (`Math.random` returns a result in `[0,1[`), which makes `96`, not `60`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 65535));
```

Because maximum hex is 65536.

Maximum hex: 16 ^ 4