# Use a unicode string in JSON file as function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, unicode

I'm using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448680/how-to-get-a-random-character-from-a-range-in-javascript) to create random characters:

```
String.fromCharCode(0x30A0 + Math.random() * (0x30FF - 0x30A0 + 1));
```

I created a function with the same principle so I can change the first and the last character of the range:

```
function uni_char(first, last) {
  var char = String.fromCharCode(first + Math.random() * (last - first + 1))
  return char;
}
```

For example, if I run the function with *0x0000* and *0x007F* as parameters, it works as expected. What I'm trying to do is to read a JSON file with multiple character ranges to use them with the function. This is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "first": "0x0000",
    "last": "0x007F"
  },
  {
    "first": "0x0080",
    "last": "0x00FF"
  }
]
```

I populate an array with the JSON file data using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235473/how-to-create-javascript-array-from-external-file-json):

```
var blocks = [];

$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url: '/scripts/data/blocks.json',
  data: "",
  accepts:'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      blocks.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

But when I use the values from the array with the function:

```
uni_char(blocks[0].first, blocks[0].last);
```

It just creates a � symbol. What am I missing? Maybe an encoding problem? Or a logic problem?

Comment: Your hex _"numbers"_ are strings. You should parse them into integers first, eg `parseInt(first, 16)`

Comment: Thank you. That's it.